# Выравнивание flex-элементов по правому краю

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap

Подскажите, как в моем примере правильно выравнять элементы по правому краю?

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(../img/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center / cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.header::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1000;
}

.header__nav {
  display: flex;
}

.header__menu-list {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header class="header" id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="header__nav">
      <div class="header__logo logo">
        <a href="#" class="header__logo-link">Landing Page №1</a>
      </div>
      
      <ul class="header__menu-list">
        <li class="header__menu-item">
          <a href="#">Услуги</a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__menu-item">
          <a href="#">Форма</a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__menu-item">
          <a href="#">Подвал</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: обычное свойство css - float: ...

Answer (score 0):

Выравнивание элементов по горизонтали делается свойством justify-content.

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(../img/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center / cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.header::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1000;
}

.header__nav {
  display: flex;
}

.header__menu-list {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end; // Выравнивание по правому краю

}
```

```html
<header class="header" id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="header__nav">
      <div class="header__logo logo">
        <a href="#" class="header__logo-link">Landing Page №1</a>
      </div>
      
      <ul class="header__menu-list">
        <li class="header__menu-item">
          <a href="#">Услуги</a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__menu-item">
          <a href="#">Форма</a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__menu-item">
          <a href="#">Подвал</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое!

Answer (score 0):

У вас как минимум 2 способа:
1) Используя класс Bootstrap 4: "ml-auto" или "d-flex justify-content-end" 
2) Используя flex: justify-content: flex-end;